# Partial display on mapkit view

Tags: ios, mapkit, countries

I'm facing an issue with MapKit for too long now and I really need your help to find where the problem might come from...
I'm drawing countries borders on a mapkit view. To do so, I add a customized polygon object as an overlay to my map. When it is added, the "viewForOverlay" method returns an overlay view which has the country shape and a specific color that depends on the value of a parameter for this country. Unfortunately, when I try to draw these countries only the polygons located in a square on the left upper corner of the map are displayed, the others remaining invisible... And those who only partially belongs to this square are simply cut...

Would anyone have an hint about where my issue might come from or what could explain this quite strange behavior ?

Great thanks !

Benja

Comment: Is this for iOS?  Are you using MKPolygon or a custom overlay class?  If it's a custom class, how is boundingMapRect being set?

Comment: Hi Anna ! Yes this is on iOS. In fact I just extend the MKPolygon class to add parameters (the value I speak about above and that help me to correctly to properly colorize my countries). When the standard "viewForOverlay" method is called I just identify when the call comes from my customized class and return a mkpolygonView as explained above. Would you have an idea ? Or do you need more information ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posting some of the extension code including how boundingMapRect is set might help.  Also add the iOS tag to the question.

Comment: I added the iOS tag, thanks for the advise ;) ! Concerning the boundingMapRect, I don't set it at all. Is this a MKPolygon method called with "viewForOverlay" ? In that case, I use the standard one... What does it do exactly ? Here is the code for the method that actually draws my countries, in case the problem would come from there... Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: - (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {
if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[CountryPolygon class]]){
CountryPolygon *proPolygon = overlay;
MKPolygonView *aView = [[[MKPolygonView alloc]initWithPolygon:[proPolygon polygon]] autorelease];
 if ([[proPolygon purchasingPowerCategory] isEqualToString:@"nc"]) {
   aView.fillColor = [[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
 } else {
   aView.fillColor = [[UIColor greenColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
 }
aView.strokeColor = [[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
return aView;  
}

Comment: CountryPolygon is my customized class I told you about previously :) ! I'm sorry, I know the code above is not easy to read but I could find how to properly post code here...

Comment: And lastly, here is a screenshot of what I get on simulator (same on device) just to make sure that you see exactly how strange this is ;) ! http://www.megaupload.com/?d=0YWO3JIF

Comment: Hi again Anna ! Just to tell you that I tried to see the boundingMapRect of my customized class and received a BAD ACCESS EXCEPTION. After a few sets, this now works perfectly ! Thanks a lot for your help !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it might help some of you, I just wanted to let you know that I finally managed to make it work thanks to Anna's help. When creating a customized overlay class (even when it directly inherits from a standard class such as MKPolygon), the boundingMapRectObject needs to be set as a property of your class (that's at least the way I solved it). Hope it will help some of you !